# PHP Enable bz2 Extension In Php.ini

Tags: php, composer-php, php-ini, bzip2

I an trying to download a file using composer in php, but the file needs to be decompress with bzipped. Here is the error I get:

```
[UnexpectedValueException]                                                   
unable to decompress bzipped phar archive "/home/admin/public_html/subdo  
mains/testing4/vendor/jakoch/phantomjs/da2db411008833dfaa24e92e129aa037.bz2  
" to temporary file, enable bz2 extension in php.ini
```

In my php.ini file I have added:

```
extension = "bz2.so"
```

After adding that I still get the error when I try and install the file.

When I run infophp(-1) I get:

```
bzip2 compression   disabled (install pecl/bz2)
```

Do I need to enable bzip2? If so how do I do it. Am I doing something wrong with allowing the extension?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php

Answer (score 15):

You can install this as php extension easily.

```
apt-get install php5.6-bz2
```

- php(yourversion)-bz2

[Source](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/php-bz2)

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem installing https://github.com/jakoch/phantomjs-installer in Homestead. It was requiring bz2.

Comment: You can use `sudo apt-get install php-bz2` for php 7.0 and 7.1

Comment: This solved my problem as well while installing phantomjs on php 7.2 thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Enabling an extention in PHP is not only by including it into `php.ini` file, you need to recompile your PHP installation with package support being enabled, in order to do this for bz2, you have to execute the needed pecl command:

```
pecl install bz2
```

To install `pecl` you have to install `pear` and `phpize`, on a debian based system, the following command should be sufficint:

```
apt-get install php5-dev php-pear
```

Finally you need to add the new extension to `php.ini` file, Don't forget to reload your web server after that.

HTH